# HTML adjustments

Tags: html, css

I made the following website (http://abrradesignstudio.com/) using a HTML builder template.

Looking at the categories (All, Brochures, Resumes.... etc.) I see that they are somehow aligned to the left. Maybe they are centered, but if the row is not sufficient, it makes a new one, leaving the first one with too much space to the right (making it look left aligned).
How can I avoid that and make them really centered?

Is there a fast way to make all other images disappear (instead of dim/gray-out in the background) when selecting a certain category?

Another question: My contact form is not working. I saw on a similar website that they use https://formspree.io/.
I did the same, but I still get an error submitting. My code is 1:1 with the other one (that works), just the e-mail is different.

Comment: Take a read of this please: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know very little about HTML or CSS it may be best to read up some blogs and tutorials on CSS (there are many, many out on the net) .

### The Solution

In `.filters li` (*line 4542 in theme-nearblack.css*) turn off `float:left;` and your display will show as you want.

floats do just that, they float outside of the flow of the document so it's much more tedious to try and centre them. As the parent element to this `li` is already floated there isn't much point floating the contents as well.

### Stack Overflow Questions

Please when asking questions can you paste a minimum working version  of your code which displays your problem, rather than links to external websites **which will change**. Posting code blocks into your question means whenever someone in the future reads your question they can see exactly the issues you are having (and how they are solved).

Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

If my solution works for you can you mark up and tick, thanks.

Comment: yes, it worked. Thank you for the help and the advice on posting/learning. Do you have any idea about the contact form? I am not sure where to look about it.

Comment: @alex747 unfortunately you have not given enough details to help with that, do you have an account with FormSpree? What server side technology do you use? Have you set up your `<form>` with the correct data? Formspree should have a guide for users to copy/paste forms into their pages, for Formspree to handle once they're submitted. This question as it stands is too open and vague for me to give you practical advice, sorry.